# Docker not supported on 32-bit OS

Tags: docker, operating-system

I am new to docker and was wondering if someone can explain to me on a **technical level** why docker is not supported on 32-bit Operating Systems. I have tried researching this question but could not find a very clear answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a technical level, there is no reason, as it works.

But Docker should add resources to support it.

The same way Oracle or any other company does not support software that do work.